How do I identify which vertex to start with when constructing an irregular curve of constant width?
A Curve of Constant Width (CoCW) is a closed, convex curve whose width (measured as the distance between parallel supporting lines) is the same in all directions. A CoCW can be constructed from any strictly-convex polygon with an odd number of vertices $n$ by the following procedure:

Pick one of the vertices as a starting point.
Label the vertex points $P_i$, counter-clockwise from the starting point $P_1$ to the last point $P_n$.
Draw a circular arc centered on $P_{1 + \frac{n + 1}{2}}$, starting at $P_1$ and ending where it intersects the line through $P_2$ and $P_{1 + \frac{n + 1}{2}}$. Call the ending point $Q_2$.
Draw a circular arc centered on $P_2$, starting at $Q_2$ and ending where it intersects the line through $P_2$ and $P_{2 + \frac{n + 1}{2}}$. Call the ending point $Q_3$.
Repeat steps 3 and 4, incrementing all the subscripts each time (subtracting $n$ as necessary to keep the subscript-values for $P_i$ in the interval $[1, n]$), until you return to the starting point.

If you pick the correct starting point, the circular arcs will always end on the outside of the polygon and the end of the final arc will perfectly meet up with the beginning of the first arc:

However, if you pick the wrong starting point, one or more of the circular arcs will end inside the polygon, and (depending on how you implement the generating procedure) the curve will have self-intersections, lose convexity, and/or fail to close:


The problem is identifying which vertex to start with.
How do I identify the correct starting point for an arbitrary convex odd-sided polygon without manually checking each vertex?
I've tried things like "the vertex opposite the shortest edge", "the vertex with the smallest internal angle", and "the vertex farthest from the average position of all vertices", but it's pretty easy to find an arrangement of vertices that causes each of those to fail.
